# Getting error at building the Kernel Xiaomi Mi A2 (jasmine_sprout)

Tags: android, compilation, kernel

I have been trying to [build the Kernel Xiaomi Mi A2 (jasmine_sprout)](https://lineageosroms.com/jasmine_sprout/#build) for a week now and still get the always the same error, though I'm able to build other versions from time to time. I'm trying to make a custom kernel to support NetHunter function.

Here are the [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAZ8f.jpg) and the [log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ggan8EfQ57FN9pSlHU7uVLo1RPa0OYZb/view?usp=share_link).

What might be the problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect the error message to be in the question post as **text**, not linked as *image*. Also make sure to post the **first** error message, not the line with meaning "found the error, stop building". See [ask] and edit the question post accordingly.